# How to define mapping for nested classes with different properties?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have the following classes

```
class Employment{
 public string Company{get; set;}
 public string Since{get; set;}
 public string Position{get; set;}
}

class Person{
 public string FullName {get; set;}
 public Employment Employment{get; set;}
}
```

I wish to convert it to the following class

```
class PersonEntity{
 public string FullName {get; set;}
 public string EmploymentCompany{get; set;}
 public string EmploymentSince{get; set;}
 public string EmploymentPosition{get; set;}
}
```

I have defined mapping as follow

```
mce.CreateMap<Person, PersonEntity>();

mce.CreateMap<Employment, PersonEntity>
.ForMember(d=>d.EmploymentCompany, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.Company))
.ForMember(d=>d.EmploymentSince, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.Since))
.ForMember(d=>d.EmploymentPosition, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.Position))
.ForAllOtherMembers(o=>o.Ignore())
;
```

When I run, it gives me first Error at d.EmploymentCompany is not mapped. if I add Ignore() then it gives error at EmploymentSince is not mapped.

What is the correct way to map this?

Comment: The title of the question is incorrect, for it is just an object referencing another one, rather than "Nested class" which is a concept that a class that is defined inside the definition of another one.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to map your class is following:

```
 CreateMap<Person, PersonEntity>()
                .ForMember(d => d.EmploymentCompany, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Employment.Company))
                .ForMember(d => d.EmploymentSince, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Employment.Since))
                .ForMember(d => d.EmploymentPosition, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Employment.Position)) ;
```